# How does an expansion valve cool fluid?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, refrigeration

How does fluid loose temperature after leaving an expansion valve in a refrigeration cycle? Where does this heat go?

Comment: Expand the gas takes work, and that energy has to come from somewhere. it coems from the thermal energy.

Comment: Fun fact, not all fluids always get colder. Some increase in temp in certain kinds of expansion. It depends on how entropic the expansion is, what the starting temp and pressure are, and the composition of the gas. Joule Thompson Effect - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect

Comment: the valve does not cool the fluid

Comment: Why can your aerosol deodorant can get cold when you use it? Check out free expansion.

Answer (score 0):

#### The "heat" didn't go anywhere.

The heat goes into making the gas expand, the same way that we had to put energy into the gas to previously compress it.

Comment: This gives the impression that the process is mostly reversible. The expansion devices used in HVAC use non-reversible, highly entropic processes that are not related to compression work.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal Gas law "Guy Lussacs" law. When a pressure is exerted upon a working fluid, in a fixed volume it's temperature will change. When a gas is pressurized, thermal energy typically is applied into the system, when the volume increases as the fluid is ejected. Usually a fan or passive evaporative heat dissipator disposes of the waste heat.